# mongoengine cross object links

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'll really new in mongo and mongoengine. I'll whant to create object like this:

```
class Candle(Document):
    value = IntField()
    next = ReferenceField(Candle)
    prev = ReferenceField(Candle)
```

For using like this:

```
if Candle.value > Candle.next.value:
    do smf
```

Is it possible?
I'll really glad to see some useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the string 'self' as the argument to ReferenceField when you're referring to the class being defined.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same issue, and I found the solution. I know it's been a while since the question has been asked, but it still may be usefull for some people.

Try:

```
class Candle(Document):
    value = IntField()
    next = ReferenceField('Candle')
    prev = ReferenceField('Candle')
```

Using quotes will avoid circular imports and everything should work as wanted.